# Space expansion explainable by a 4D universe?

Tags: space-expansion, universe, cosmological-inflation

Could our universe be finite, but in 4D? Basically that the universe that we experience is a 3D slice of a 4D body that moves through our 3D "plane". The "big bang" then occured when the 4D universe first touched our "plane" which also explains why the universe was infinitely small at that point. Then the 4D body moves through our 3D plane, exposing more of its volume to us which we experience as inflation and explain with "dark energy".

Quite like a cone shaped fishing net with floatable objects in it. If you sink it into water, at first the water surface in the net is very small and everything is packed together. When you sink it deeper, the water surface becomes larger and the objects in the net can move away from each other.

Possible? Likely? Dumb? Let me know what you think!

Answer (score 0):

In such a model, we would also expand with the universe, and the expansion would never have been measurable from a three dimensional vantage point, but it is an interesting idea nonetheless. Have an upvote.

Comment: Could gravity be stronger than the expansive forces?

Comment: Possibly, but why would we never measure an increase in density? Shouldn't the density of anything with mass increase by a lot?